# Using BufferedImage to read and write JPEGs in Java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, dct

I have a program the reads in an image using the getRGB() method in the BufferedImage class, which then I perform a series of steps (DCT transformation into 8x8 blocks, quantitization, and then the inverse), and then writes back the data with BufferedImage using setRGB() to a JPEG file again.

This works perfect with a good result image. But when I run a tester to print out the last quantitization of the 8x8 coefficients from the original and formed images, the values seem to be 1 or 2 off?

For an example:

Original Quant. Coeffs: -27, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, etc

Resultant Quant. Coeffs: -28, 1, 0, 0, 0, etc

Can anybody figure out why does this occurs, or can this be normal?
I hope this is clear on the problem.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with the specific calculations you're making, but it sounds like a precision issue.  How are you storing the data internally?  Try using doubles to perform your calculations if you aren't already.

Comment: Actually, I'm not using doubles, but either way, will the resultant image not have the same values from the original?

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with the exact calculation you're doing, but for example: If you take a matrix, invert it, then invert it again -- if you don't have enough precision, your calculation will be susceptible to round-off error, and the resulting matrix might differ from the original.  Maybe similar in concept to what you are experiencing.  Try doing all your calculations using doubles, making sure you aren't rounding off anywhere and see if it matters.

Comment: Ahh, I just re-arranged all integers with doubles, and I only rounded up before the representing back into pixels, and now I am getting accurate results. Thanks alot for your help